# How to check if MySQL connections are using named pipe

Tags: mysql

I set up a website running PHP on the same server as MySQL. I have enabled MySQL to accept named pipe connections.

When using "show processlist", I can see the list of connections with the HOST column being "localhost:xxxxx" where xxxxx are integers.

My question is how to know if the connections are using named pipe or TCP?

Comment: It's seems like you can't with show processlist.Good luck